# Unwrapping the UV Mesh: Project from View (Bounds) giving distorted image

Tags: uv, blenderkit

I was following this tutorial to add an animation to my picture: [Tutorial video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CD-RM2SMek0)

Of course, I was using a different image and the result I got in end after unwrapping the UV Mesh for the figure that I wanted to animated so distorted like this in image: [image]

Here is my blend file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gcFpafb3QU3TZVlf5eeDsm4QV5kLJHZp/view?usp=sharing

I tried the following things to adjust this distortion:

1. Subdividing the mesh into many cuts.
2. Adding a subdivision surface modifier and using Simple mode and increasing the level cuts.
3. This video of marking seam [Video link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y7M-B6xnaEM)

One more thing, I am using (Project from View (Bounds) option for unwrapping)

[image: Image unwrapping]

But nothing seems to be working. Can anyone help me with the same ?

Comment: please provide blend file

Comment: @Chris I have attached the blend file now.

Answer (score 0):

as you can read here:

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/editors/uv_image/uv/editing/unwrapping/mapping_types.html

**Project from View (Bounds)**

```
With Bounds will do the same as Project from View but with Scale to Bounds and Correct Aspect activated.
```

Which means it will "fit" your model into the image size. So you can either change your image size by doing

[image]

and then enter a size which better fits to your view/model like this:

[image]

or you just use project from view.

or you select all vertices in UV Editor on the left side:

[image]

and press S X to scale it as you need it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. your mesh is not flat which creates the lines. scale to 0 in the x axis to fix that.
2. you unwrap from view to bounds stretches your image, use regular unwrap or unwrap from view.

Here is an improved file: https://we.tl/t-JZUQj9axWt

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]